# Flutter app on linux: window goes blank when entering text in field

Tags: flutter, forms, flutter-form-builder

I have a pretty basic form widget inside a scaffold app, with a single text field.

The form uses the `flutter_form_builder` library.

```dart
// Define a corresponding State class.
// This class holds data related to the form.
class GameCreationFormState extends State<GameCreationForm> {
  // Create a global key that uniquely identifies the Form widget
  // and allows validation of the form.
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Consumer<AppModel>(builder: (context, appModel, child) {
      return FormBuilder(
        key: _formKey,
        onChanged: () {
          _formKey.currentState!.save();
          debugPrint(_formKey.currentState!.value.toString());
        },
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            FormBuilderTextField(
              autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
              name: 'title',

              key: const Key('create-game-title'),
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Game title',
              ),
              // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter some text';
                }
                return null;
              },
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              key: const Key('create-game-submit'),
              onPressed: () {
                // Validate returns true if the form is valid, or false otherwise.
                if (_formKey.currentState!.saveAndValidate() ?? false) {
                  // I assume this will be the value of whatever what entered in the field
                  debugPrint(_formKey.currentState?.value.toString());
                }
              },
              child: const Text('Submit'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

When I run the application using `flutter run -d linux`, as soon as I start typing text in the field, the whole window becomes blank (black in my case since I'm in dark mode.)

I see no error in the logs, and the debugPrint for `onChanged` is properly called with the content of the input.

Is that a limitation of running on linux ?

Comment: it doesn't seems limitation, please add the log error(s).

Comment: I see no error in the `flutter run...` output. Is there another file / process that I should monitor for errors ?